# Ground cable from battery to motor can not find stud to attach cable. Where is it located?

Tags: electrical, oldsmobile, ground

350 Oldsmobile Cutlass. There is terminal ring that should attach to stub on motor.  When I looked at battery / motor cable was dangling loose cable length about 2 feet.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what year of Cutlass you have, but these can be attached to the bolt which goes through the case of the alternator (the one the alternator pivots on). This allows for a good ground to the engine and to the alternator. You also want to ensure there's a good body ground in there somewhere. There's usually a smaller wire which is attached to the battery cable which acts as a ground strap.

Answer (score 1):

On my 70 C20 with a 350, the ground wire goes to the A/C bracket.  Any place unpainted on the head or block should be fine.